# Finding business date within range

Tags: shell-script

I need only the business date (Mon-Fri) from the below (in bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
startdate=20141030
enddate=20141120

dates=()
for (( date="$startdate"; date != enddate; )); do
    dates+=( "$date" )
    date="$(date --date="$date + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')"
done
echo "${dates[@]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your script the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
startdate=20141030
enddate=20141120

dates=()
for (( date="$startdate"; date != enddate; )); do
    if [ "$(date --date="$date" +'%u')" -le "5" ]; then
      dates+=( "$date" )
    fi
    date="$(date --date="$date + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')"
done
echo "${dates[@]}"
```

I just added the `if`-clause before you add the date to the array. The %u sequence of `date` represents:

```
    %u     day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday
```

So, if that value is less or equal (`-le`) to `5`, it is monday - friday.