# Get date of next Saturday from a given date

Tags: shell-script, date

I want the date of the coming Saturday after a given date.
For example, for `$date1="30-AUG-2015"`, I want the result 05-SEP-2015.

I have tried all the commands below with no success:

```
samba@samba:~$ date1="30-AUG-2015"
samba@samba:~$ date2=$(date --date='"$date1" +next Saturday')
date: invalid date ‘"$date1" +next Saturday’

samba@samba:~$ date1="30-AUG-2015"
samba@samba:~$ date2=$(date --date1='next Saturday')
date: unrecognized option '--date1=next Saturday'
Try 'date --help' for more information.

samba@samba:~$ date1="30-AUG-2015"
samba@samba:~$ date -d "$date1 next saturday"
Sun Aug 30 00:00:00 IST 2015
samba@samba:~$ $date1 -d "next saturday"
30-AUG-2015: command not found
```

Answer (score 10):

I highly recommend [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) for things like this.

On Fedora Linux 21+ or CentOS/RHEL with EPEL:

```
dnf install dateutils
```

(`yum` instead of DNF on older RHEL.)

On Debian-based systems, the package is also called `dateutils` but the commands are prefixed with `dateutils.` to disambiguate some of them from commands with the same names in unrelated packages (so, replace `dateround` with `dateutils.dround` below).

Then, just do:

```
dateround today sunday
```

You can use "today" or replace with an actual date:

```
$ dateround 2015-08-30 saturday
2015-09-05
```

If you need the input date to be in a specific format, like your 30-AUG-2015, you can use the `-i` or `--input-format` option, like:

```
$ dateround -i '%d-%b-%Y' 30-AUG-2015 saturday
2015-09-05
```

It's not immediately clear from the name "dateround", but this command *rounds up* — that is, it won't round back to the previous Sunday on Monday. It also defaults to returning the current day if it matches — like, if today is Sunday, and `dateround today sunday` will give today's date. If you want it to always be a future date, add the `--next` flag.

Answer (score 4):

With `ksh93`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C ksh93 -c 'printf "%(%c)T\n" "30-Aug-2015 Saturday"'
Sat Sep  5 00:00:00 2015
```

Note that if the date is a Saturday, then it will return that same day, if you want the next Saturday, make it:

```
LC_ALL=C printf "%(%c)T\n" "30-Aug-2015 tomorrow Saturday"
```

Replace `%c` with the `strftime` spec you want:

```
$ LC_ALL=C printf "%(%d-%b-%Y)T\n" "03-Jan-2015 tomorrow saturday"
10-Jan-2015
```

To make it `10-JAN-2015`, assign it to a variable declared with `typeset -u`:

```
typeset -u date=${
  LC_ALL=C printf "%(%d-%b-%Y)T\n" "03-Jan-2015 tomorrow saturday"
}
```

With the GNU implementation of `date`:

```
$ d=03-JAN-2015
$ LC_ALL=C date -d "$d +1 week -$(date -d "$d +1 day" +%w) day" '+%d-%^b-%Y'
10-JAN-2015
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reponse Sir. But my date can be any day of the week.

Comment: @shiv, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

### Single-line solution for any day week without loops

```
MON=1
TUE=2
WED=3
THU=4
FRI=5
SAT=6
SUN=7

echo "Today "          && date
echo "Next Monday "    && date -d "+ $(( ( (6 + $MON - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) days"
echo "Next Tuesday "   && date -d "+ $(( ( (6 + $TUE - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) days"
echo "Next Wednesday " && date -d "+ $(( ( (6 + $WED - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) days"
echo "Next Thursday "  && date -d "+ $(( ( (6 + $THU - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) days"
echo "Next Friday "    && date -d "+ $(( ( (6 + $FRI - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) days"
echo "Next Saturday "  && date -d "+ $(( ( (6 + $SAT - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) days"
echo "Next Sunday "    && date -d "+ $(( ( (6 + $SUN - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) days"
```

**Output**

```
Today
Thu, Nov 12, 2020 10:24:38 PM
Next Monday
Mon, Nov 16, 2020 10:24:39 PM
Next Tuesday
Tue, Nov 17, 2020 10:24:40 PM
Next Wednesday
Wed, Nov 18, 2020 10:24:40 PM
Next Thursday
Thu, Nov 19, 2020 10:24:41 PM
Next Friday
Fri, Nov 13, 2020 10:24:42 PM
Next Saturday
Sat, Nov 14, 2020 10:24:42 PM
Next Sunday
Sun, Nov 15, 2020 10:24:43 PM
```

**Explanation**

Idea is to calculate number of days until next day of week and add these number to current date. Let's take Saturday as example.

- On Monday add 5 days
- ...
- On Friday add 1 day
- On Saturday add 7 days
- On Sunday add 6 days

So first iteration of algorithm looks like take current day of week `date +%u`, take `mod 7` and add `1` because modulo is zero based:

`( $(date +%u) % 7) + 1`

However, it does not take into account that our sequence of days to add is descending (5,4,3,2,1,7,6). To accommodate this we have to subtract current day of week from `7`, then take modulo and add `1`:

`( (7 - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1`

So we got working example for Monday (`7 == 6 + $MON`). To make it searching any week of day we should re-write it like

`( (6 + <DAY> - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1`

where `<DAY>` should be any of variables above (`$MON`...`$SUN`)

### Modification for Alpine Linux

Alpine Linux does not support `-d "+ 3 days"` so you either install `coreutils`  (`apk add coreutils`) to make it working or do days arithmetic by yourself.

```
date -d "@$(($(date +%s) + 86400 * $(( ( (6 + $SAT - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) ))"
```

**Explanation**

`$(date +%s)` outputs number of seconds since ... you know! `86400` is number of seconds per day, `date -d "@<number_of_seconds>"` restores date from modified number of seconds.

### Modification for Mac OS

It works like "Modification for Alpine Linux" except on MacOS, instead of `date -d "@<number_of_seconds>"` you write `date -r "<number_of_seconds>"`, so

```
date -r "$(($(date +%s) + 86400 * $(( ( (6 + $SAT - $(date +%u)) % 7) + 1 )) ))"
```

See "Modification for Alpine Linux/Explanation" above for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I presume from what you tried that you want a single command. 
I couldn’t find one, but I adapted [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202906/23408) to do what you want:

```
# Assume that date1 is already set to "30-AUG-2015"
try_date="$date1"
while [ "$(date --date="$try_date" +"%A")" != Saturday ]
do
    try_date=$(date --date="$try_date + 1 day" +"%d-%b-%Y")
done
date2="$try_date"
echo "$date2"
```

Output:

```
05-Sep-2015
```

You can change the `while` line to either

- `while [ "$(date --date="$try_date" +"%a")" != Sat ]`
  or
- `while [ "$(date --date="$try_date" +"%5")" != 6 ]`
  (use `1` for Monday … `7` for Sunday)

If `$date1` is “29-Aug-2015” (which is a Saturday),
then `$date2` will be “29-Aug-2015” (i.e., the same day). 
If you still want to get 05-Sep-2015 for this input
(i.e., the next Saturday *after* `$date1`), change the first line
to `try_date=$(date --date="$date1 + 1 day" +"%d-%b-%Y")`.

If you really want the month in all capitals (e.g., “SEP”), use `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution a lot simpler to write is:

```
$ adate1="30-AUG-2015"

$ faketime "$adate1" date -d 'saturday' +'%d-%b-%Y'

05-Sep-2015
```

Of course, you need to install faketime.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer to this question is:

```
IFS="#"; ((
for s_date in $(echo ${date1}' +'{1..7}' days#'); do 
date -d "${s_date}";
done
) | grep Sat
) | xargs -I {} date +%d-%b-%Y -d "{}"
```

Output:

```
05-Sep-2015
```

This creates a list of `#` separated strings like:

```
"30-AUG-2015 +1 days# 30-AUG-2015 +2 days# 30-AUG-2015 +3 days# ..."
```

That list is then looped through and passed to `date`, where I can `grep` for the day I'm looking for (e.g. Sat). Lastly I can use `xargs` to convert the output to the format you're looking for. 
The code can be put in a single line for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more straight forward than some of the other answers:

```
startdate=30-AUG-2015
weekday=saturday
date -d "$startdate + $(( (`date +%u -d $weekday` - `date +%u -d $startdate` + 7 ) % 7 )) day"
```

That takes the `$startdate` and gives you the next `$weekday`.  It's a little verbose, because `date` does not like adding "next Saturday" to an arbitrary date; instead, we can only add a number of days.

So, to break that command down with what it's doing:

```
date -d "$startdate + $((                                   `# begin arithmetic`
                           (  `date +%u -d $weekday`        `# what day of week (1..7) is the desired week day`
                              -                             `# subtract day of week of $startdate from the target $weekday`
                               `date +%u -d $startdate`     `# the week day of the $startdate`
                              + 7                           `# ensure value is positive (in case desired $weekday is before the $startdate weekday)`
                           )  % 7                           `# modulo 7 for actual number of days between the two weekdays`
                       )) day"                              `# end arithmetic and specify value as seconds`
```

Comment: Both code blocks will work as copy-and-paste.  Note that the comments in the second block are inside of backticks, creating a subshell that only has a comment.   Without spawning a subshell like that, bash will not accept comments in a multi-line command